# how to have fade in/out on audio HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a simple background music which has only one button to play and stop the music. But I would like to add fade to it. But does not work.

My code:

```
var beepTwo = $("#musicBeat")[0];
beepTwo.play();



$("#dan").click(function() {
  if (beepTwo.paused == false) {
      beepTwo.pause();

  } else {
      beepTwo.play();
  }
});


$beepTwo.animate({volume: newVolume}, 1000);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PE3yw/1/)

I found `$audio.animate({volume: newVolume}, 1000);`in another post but does not work for me or maybe I didnt use it correctly. Anyway I want to have a fade in and fade out when the button is pressed. So it plays with fadeIn and stops with fadeOut. How can I do that?

Comment: you have to set a value in newVolume, and the logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to watch out for the difference between the HTMLAudioElement (`$('#musicBeat')[0]`) and the jQuery Object (`$('#musicBeat')`).

`play` is a method of the HTMLAudioElement, so you'll have to access it over that (as you did), but `.animate` is a jQuery method and can only be called on a jQuery object.

And you have to specify newVolume (can't leave it empty).

```
var beepTwo = $("#musicBeat");
beepTwo[0].play();

$("#dan").click(function() {  
    if (beepTwo[0].paused == false) {
        beepTwo.animate({volume: 0}, 2000, 'swing', function() {
            // really stop the music 
            beepTwo[0].pause();   
        });
     } else {
         beepTwo[0].play();  
         beepTwo.animate({volume: 1}, 2000);
     }
});
```

Comment: With your code the track can't be started again, however, the music fades out.

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize that the element only is `paused` after calling `.pause()`(makes sense, though).

I edited my answer to fix that issue.