# Javascript: adjusting script for multiple audio players and fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to adjust this code to make it work with multiple players in one page and adding a fade effect when pausing/replaying:

```
var playing = false;
playpause.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player').play();
        this.src = 'pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player').pause();
        this.src = 'play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
```

This unbearable snippet is what I'm using right now to make it work with different tracks (using different IDs)....

```
var playing = false;
playpause01.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player01').play();
        this.src = 'pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player01').pause();
        this.src = 'play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
playpause04.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player04').play();
        this.src = 'pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player04').pause();
        this.src = 'play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
playpause13.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!playing) {
        document.getElementById('player13').play();
        this.src = 'pause.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('player13').pause();
        this.src = 'play.png';
    }
    playing = !playing;
});
```

Here's the "working" JSFiddle with HTML and JS:
**http://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/jdk0b5L4/**

So, how can I rewrite that to mix the tracks in one same function, stop playing one track if other is selected and add a fade effect ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Are you familiar with state machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..

I am assuming that you are not using jQuery for a reason?, which makes fading a pain.

but I have managed to clean the code a bit for you, so that adding the fading is easier. Each sound is given its field in a playing array, for monitoring that sounds state.

(each place in the playing array is set to true/false, but could be "stopped", "fading in", "playing", "fading out",)

http://jsfiddle.net/jdk0b5L4/2/

```
var playing = [];

images =  document.getElementsByTagName("img")
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
    if(images[i].hasAttribute("class") && images[i].getAttribute("class") == "playPause")
    {
        images[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.info("pressed play/pause on ", this)
            var ID = this.getAttribute("id").replace("playpause", "")

            if (!playing[ID]) {
                document.getElementById('player' + ID).play();
                this.src = 'http://luca-longobardi.com/files/img/pause.png';
                playing[ID] = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('player' + ID).pause();
                this.src = 'http://luca-longobardi.com/files/img/play.png';
                playing[ID] = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

I recommend this method for fading, if you can use jQuery.
[how to have fade in/out on audio HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611448/how-to-have-fade-in-out-on-audio-html5)

if you insist on not using jquery, please comment it, and I'll see if I can work something out that can fade in and out using plain vanilla javascript..

updated to fit comment:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdk0b5L4/5/

Comment: ps forgot, I added a class to the images in the html part... `class="playPause"`

Comment: Thanks! I tried the jsfiddle but it's not stopping the previous song when playing a new one.

Comment: in the `if(!playing..`  statement, add a loop, that runs through all the audio tags, `for(var j = 0; j < document.getElementsByTagName("audio").length; j++){}` and run the same code as shown in the `else` statement, just dont do it for the one audio element called `"player" + ID`

Comment: Thanks. Will award the bounty when timer resets.

Answer (score 3):

Create a wrapper object that will reference an audio element as well as dealing with fade-in/out.

Then use common handler for the `play` event, and use the `this` object to distinguish between the different audio elements.

This approach uses just the audio element avoiding Web Audio API and CORS requirements. We don't want to handle pause events as we would need to force-play, which would trigger play event, and force us to do special hack-ish treatment.

It is not bound to any ID and can handle any audio element on a page - to narrow down use a different query-selector definition. It also starts the first time with the element's audio value, and can detect if it's the only one paused meaning it can pause/play without any fade-out/in.

## Example

Part of this code is taken from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771457/how-can-i-determine-if-standard-audio-player-is-playing-a-song/30793057#30793057) with modification to implement fade functionality:

```js
var audioElements = document.querySelectorAll("audio"), i, // get all audio elements
    audioWrappers = [];                                    // holds our wrapper object

// bind common handler for each audio element in page:
for(i = 0; i < audioElements.length; i++) {
  audioWrappers.push(new AudioFader(audioElements[i]));    // create wrapper
  audioElements[i].addEventListener("play", playHandler);  // add handler
}

// common handler for play
function playHandler() {
  // this = element triggering the even - fade-out all others but ours
  for(var i = 0, w; w = audioWrappers[i]; i++) {
    if (this !== w.audio) w.fadeOut(1500, 1);
    else w.fadeIn(1500, 1);
  }
}

// wrapper
function AudioFader(audio) {
  var isPausing = false;
  this.audio = audio;                              // expose so we can compare

  this.fadeIn = function(time, dst) {              // fade-in (time in ms, dst volume)
    isPausing = false;
    audio.play();                                  // play
    if (audio.volume === dst) return;              // hasn't been faded-out
    var startTime = Date.now();                    // start-time
    (function loop() {
      var t = (Date.now() - startTime) / time;     // normalize t [0, 1]
      audio.volume = Math.min(1, t) * dst;         // set volume, max 1
      if (!isPausing && t < dst)                   // loop if t to go and not pausing
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    })();
  };
  
  this.fadeOut = function(time, src) {             // fade-out (time in ms, src volume)
    isPausing = true;
    if (audio.paused) return;                      // exit if already paused
    audio.volume = src;                            // start with src volume
    var startTime = Date.now();
    (function loop() {
      var t = (Date.now() - startTime) / time;
      audio.volume = Math.max(0, 1 - t) * src;     // t is 0..1, so reverse 1-t
      if (isPausing && t < 1) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      else {
        audio.pause();                             // eventually pause
        audio.volume = 0;                          // mute volume
      }
    })();
  };
}
```

```html
<i>Preload time may vary, be patient... (due to links IE will not be able to play these)</i><br>Starting one will stop all others<br>
<audio preload="auto" controls src="https://github.com/epistemex/free-music-for-test-and-demo/blob/master/music/kf_feelme.mp3?raw=true"></audio><br>
<audio preload="auto" controls src="https://github.com/epistemex/free-music-for-test-and-demo/blob/master/music/kf_colibris.mp3?raw=true"></audio><br>
<audio preload="auto" controls src="https://github.com/epistemex/free-music-for-test-and-demo/blob/master/music/kf_limitless.mp3?raw=true"></audio><br>
<audio preload="auto" controls src="https://github.com/epistemex/free-music-for-test-and-demo/blob/master/music/kf_thebattle.mp3?raw=true"></audio>
```

Comment: This is much better :)