# Change Data-Property Value Over 10 Seconds

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have this code, and I'm wanting to change the data-property "vol" from 100 to 0 over 10 seconds (so the sound fades out). How would I manage to do this?

```
    <div class="pattern-overlay">
  <a id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYh3WAf8CXI',
    containment:'.video-section', 
    quality:'large', 
    autoPlay:true, 
    vol:100, 
    mute:false, 
   opacity:1}">bg</a>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Are you sure that just changing the property in the `data` cache will actually affect the volume of the related control? I'd be very surprised if it did.

Comment: I'm hoping it does, I've only been able to test the volume change by changing the attribute value manually and reloading the page.

Comment: In that case simply changing the value dynamically will not work - it's only read on page load. If you can give some more details about what you're actually trying to achieve there is probably a better way

Comment: It's a short video of a lightning animation with thunder. I'm having it load full screen and then the page will fade out into the next one. I'm needing the volume of the video to fade out too, so that it creates a smoother transition.

Comment: To do that you need to change the `volume` property on the `video` element directly. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611448/how-to-have-fade-in-out-on-audio-html5) for a possible solution. It's applied to an `audio` element, but should work for `video` too